# Illegal chars in URL

Tags: php

Users can upload files to my site.

I've checked stack overflow and looked in to various discussions on illegal URL characters.

When the user uploads a file, I wish to remove any illegal characters, some sites suggest using FILTER_SANITIZE_URL while others suggest a regex expression.

My question is, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Remove illegal characters from what?

Comment: Their both good. Use whats easier for you.

Comment: A user may have a file with illegal chars in the file they are uploading (file names stay the same). Other users can access this on the site. If it contains illegal chars it wont work.

Comment: [Check the source code of `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/filter/sanitizing_filters.c#317) to get a better understanding of what's exactly being done. You could basically rewrite it in a PCRE regex and use a regex instead but since it's already there, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: you told *When the user uploads a file* you want to remove *any illegal characters* from *url*? Are you're sure, that you mean **url** and not **$_FILES['name']**?

Comment: the name of the file is used in the url. So if someone uploads hello.jpg it will be mysite.com/files/hello.jpg

Answer (score 1):

PHP has `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` built in. In general it is considered best practice to use built in functions (when available) rather than trying to re-implement them yourself.

If you run this function on the file names before saving them you shouldn't have a problem with displaying them in the URL.

E.g. `$filename = filter_var($_FILES['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);`

Comment: I've tried this but unfortunately it still allows illegal chars such as # and <

Comment: @panthro From the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php): `Remove all characters except letters, digits and $-_.+!*'(),{}|\\^~[]\`<>#%";/?:@&=` That is because those characters are not illegal and are allowed in a URL. Read this if you want a full definition of what is allowed in a URL: [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Comment: @panthro If you want to eliminate specific characters that are not illegal I would suggest first running `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` to remove the illegal characters and then using a regex to remove / replace the additional characters that you don't want in your URL.